# For loops are disturbing rendering

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, three.js, webgl

I have some pretty simple 3D objects (basically `THREE.Sphere` which is a parent of 1-30 other `THREE.Sphere`s, with RGB color and no texture) to display in somewhat real time animation.

The rendering is done in no time indeed, but I have some simple iterative calculation (`for-loops`) that are disturbing my display capabilities.
**The rendering itself is not the problem, but the computation for the next frame vertices is what causing the pain**

Meaning, when I just run the script, I can see that the `for-loops` are taking too much time to compute, and just then it goes to the rendering section which is done in no time.

I was thinking of dealing with this problem in a parallel computing manner- running a thread (worker, whatever it is called in `JS`) that would calculate the `for-loop`, but I thought that considering my lack of experience in computer graphocs, perhaps there is a more "graphic"ed way of doing so. Meaning a more elegant/performance-improved/natural way of dealing with such a fundamental problem of computer graphics design.

Comment: It might be a good idea to show the code for the loop you think is slow.

Comment: This is what shaders are for, move your code to the GPU and it will be much faster due to the parallelism.

Comment: @BrendanAnnable - aren't shaders are for rendering? The GPU is not very effective for simple, non matrix operations. All I need (@2pha) in the for loop is some memory access, along with some compares, some kind of sorting done on a few small arrays (about 5 arrays of up to 30 integer elements each)

Comment: Depends if your for-loops are related to your rendering, i.e. is it moving things (vertices) around? If its not, and completely independent, then I guess web workers will do.

Comment: My `for-loop`'s purpose is to calculate some parameters (line width, vertices positions, RGB colors for mesh...) for the rendering. BUT, the render command it self is working fast enough, regardless of the `for-loop` results.

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic idea I am using to do long slow calculations that don't get caught by the watchdog timers and bog down the browser or the render rate.
The basic idea is that you use a javascript generator that allows you to yield in the middle of a computation, and continue later on.  Then, I run the generator pump on a timeout chain.
The key to this method is the "yield" operator that saves the function state and returns awaiting a future call to the .next() function. (btw this demo code might have to be re arraged to handle firefoxs forward references)

```
 //function Chain represents the slow code
function *Chain()
{
    for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)  //this represents a long slow calculation
    {
        if(i%100==0)        //on occassion, yield 
            yield;
    }

}
console.log("starting chain");
gChain=Chain(); //startup and get the next generator pointer
timeout = setTimeout(function () { ChainStart(); }, 1);
 //function ChainStart is a pump that runs the generator using a timeout chain so other threads can run
function ChainStart(){                 
        if(gChain.next().done){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            console.log("endingchain");                 
        }
        else{                       
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function () { ChainStart(); }, 1);
        }
}
```

Comment: You should check out [HTML5 WebWorkers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/). It might be interesting for you as an alternative to your `setTimeout` solution...

Comment: Yeah that is cool!  Thread safety sounds like it could get hairy, but in some instances this has to be better.

Comment: I used it before and it is not as difficult as it sounds. Some examples will help. You should only think about browser support...